How to separate lines with a repeated identifier from lines with a non-repeated identifier?
I would like to generate two outputs in Pentaho. One output with lines where the CPF is unique and another output as lines where the CPF is repeated. Initially I used the "Data grid" and "Sort rows" steps, but I don't know how to go about doing what I want. See the data:
Data input:

| CPF           | Nome         | Ano |
-------------------------------------|             
|636.624.160-00 |Alexandre Dias| 2023|                  
|438.815.860-75 |José da Silva | 2023|
|438.815.860-75 |José da Silva | 2022|
|311.520.000-55 |Maria Pereira | 2022|
|835.894.510-84 |Otávio Campos | 2023|
|835.894.510-84 |Otávio Campos | 2022|


Outputs I want:
Output with lines with single CPF:

| CPF           | Nome         | Ano |
-------------------------------------|             
|636.624.160-00 |Alexandre Dias| 2023|                  
|311.520.000-55 |Maria Pereira | 2022|

Output with lines with repeated CPF:
| CPF           | Nome         | Ano |
-------------------------------------|                              
|438.815.860-75 |José da Silva | 2023|
|438.815.860-75 |José da Silva | 2022|
|835.894.510-84 |Otávio Campos | 2023|
|835.894.510-84 |Otávio Campos | 2022|

Obs: CPF randomly generated.

Load data via text input as lines to record,
then in a side flow "Memory group" the data on CPF and add count field.
then add a 1 or 0 based on the count (id count = 1 then 1 else 0).
Connect your mainflow with a lookup to the sideflow, where you retrieve the 0/1 variable.
"switch step" based on 0/1 variable
on each of the two paths, write to two diffrent files.
